# What Korbanot do people say before Mincha?

Tags: korbanos-ketores-prayers

I want to try and say some Korbanot before Mincha, however, none of the siddurim I use provide it in the Mincha section. It starts with Ashrei. What do people commonly say?

i.e, Kiyor, Terumat Hadeshen, Tamid, etc.?

Comment: What nusach do you daven?

Comment: @user6781 almost certainly Ashkenaz since the siddur doesn't print korbanot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be sure what most people do, but I've seen a lot of siddurim that include Parshas Hatamid and Parshas Haketores before Ashrei. Also recommended by the [Rama](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.234.1?lang=he) (Tamid), [Magen Avraham](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.234.2?lang=he) (includes ketores), and the Mishnah Berurah [Sif Koton 6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.234.6?lang=he). [Although the Magen Avraham writes that these passages are meant to be said after אשרי see Mishnah Berurah [Sif Koton 7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.234.7?lang=he) where he writes that the מנהג does not follow that view.]

The Siddur based on the Nusach of the Arizal, called "shaar hakolel" an inclusive Nusach for all Jews, says to say Parshas Hatamid, Ketores and Ana Bechoach before Ashrei:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: But note the Magen Avraham elsewhere in 132 says about the ketoret והאר"י כ' שאין לאומרו בערב

Answer (score 1):

Rama writes (OC 234:1) approvingly of those who recite the section related to the Tamid offering before Ashrei at Mincha. He also writes (OC 132:2) to recite the section related to the incense offering after prayer in the evening. I wouldn't say either of these is common nowadays in Ashkenazi communities, though I suspect the former is more common than the latter.

You should know there is also a *lot* of debate among later commentators about the precise optimal placement of each of those passages in the service (before Ashrei, after Ashrei, after Mincha, after early Arvit) though arguably it is better to pick a spot and say it than to get confused, give up, and say nothing.

Comment: Some *siddurim* preface the recitation of these passages with that of the *kiyor*

Answer (score 0):

Here are links to the Korbanos said at Mincha.

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49762&st=&pgnum=447

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49762&st=&pgnum=448

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49762&st=&pgnum=449